# Rendered JPanel with JcheckBoxes inside an Jtable cell. Now the Panel is not getting align to centre of the cell in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jcheckbox

Cell renderer:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if(value!=null && ai38DataModel!=null){
        //panel.removeAll();
        List<AI38BetModelTable> modelList = ai38DataModel.getModelList();
        LinkedHashMap<String, JPanel> elePanelMap = ai38DataModel.getElePanelMap();
        if(modelList!=null || !modelList.isEmpty() || !elePanelMap.isEmpty()){
            AI38BetModelTable model = modelList.get(row);
            String key = ai38DataModel.getPanelEleStringKey(model.getSelectedEvent().getEventCode(), model.getSelectedBetCode(), model.getElement(), (Set<Integer>)value);
            panel = elePanelMap.get(key);
            }
        }
                  
    return panel;
    
    }
```

Adding Jchecboxes to panel:

```
                    for(Integer value: nameValuePair.get(key)){         
                        JCheckBox jChkbx = new JCheckBox(value.toString());
                        jChkbx.setOpaque(false);
                        jChkbx.addItemListener(listener);
                        panel.add(jChkbx);                          
                        }
```

[enter image description here][1]

strong text  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Mhs.png

PLease find the attached image.

Comment: Which layout you use in your pannel? Please provide a [mcve] so we can also run your code and reproduce your problem. Pleas don't post your complete code but create a small simple example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Hi @SergiyMedvynskyy, Thanks for taking your time for reply. My issue got resolved when i used GridBaglayout instead of a FlowLayout. Now the Jcheckboxes are aligned to centre inside the panel.

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved when i used GridBaglayout instead of a FlowLayout. Now the Jcheckboxes are aligned to centre inside the panel.

```
for(String key : nameValuePair.keySet()){
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
  modelList.add(new AI38BetModelTable(selectedeEvent,selectedBetCode,key,nameValuePair.get(key)));
  String keyForPanel = ai38DataModel.getPanelEleStringKey(selectedeEvent.getEventCode(), selectedBetCode, key, nameValuePair.get(key));
  for(Integer value: nameValuePair.get(key)){
    JCheckBox jChkbx = new JCheckBox(value.toString());
    jChkbx.setOpaque(false);
    jChkbx.addItemListener(listener);
    panel.add(jChkbx);
  }
  panelEleMap.put(keyForPanel, panel);
}
```